# sscanf does not correctly convert floats when size of array is fixed

Tags: c, string, floating-point, double, scanf

I am trying to use `sscanf` to convert an array of `char` in C to a `double`. My issue is best described in this short minimal working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  char string_one[]  = "1.2e-4";
  char string_two[6] = "1.2e-4";

  double one, two;

  sscanf(string_one, "%lf", &one);
  sscanf(string_two, "%lf", &two);

  printf("%e, %e\n", one, two);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with GCC and running the resulting executable returns `1.200000e-04, 1.200000e-41`, instead of the same number twice. The issue does not appear if the floating point number I want to convert is of the form `3e4`(if there is no decimal separator).

For my program I have to define an array of `char` with a fixed size (as I am filling the array during the course of the program), which is why I am running into this issue.

I guess the problem might be pretty obvious - but as I am a newbie in C I am out of ideas what the problem could be. Any help appreciated!

Comment: `string_two` is not null-terminated.

Comment: `string_two` is not a string. You cannot use it with most `<string.h>` functions, with `"%s"` in `printf()`, as 1st argument to `sscanf()`, ...

Comment: You aren't allowing enough characters for `string_two`. `"1.2e-4" needs 7 chars, not 6, since strings require a null terminator.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot guys, I hadn't heard about the null-terminator. So in general if I would construct my own string I would always have to add the null terminator `'\0'` as last character (and make each array of `char` one element longer?)

Comment: Depends on how you construct it. the initializer such as the one for `string_one` is doing it for you.

Comment: Okay got it - thank you :-) If you submit an answer I can approve it as the correct one.

Comment: Think about it -- how could `sscanf` know how long `string_two` is?

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main (int argc, char **argv)`  When the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: Note that the exponent `E-41` probably means that `string_two` was stored so that the next character was the start of `string_one`.  Had you reversed the declations, you might well get a different result.  However, any result is correct because `string_two` is misnamed because it is not a string (no null terrminator, as everyone else said).

Comment: You can limit the number of chars used for decoding the field like this: `sscanf(string_two,"%6lf",&two);`. Whether there are other side effects or not for missing null terminator in string_two is left undetermined though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char string_two[6] = "1.2e-4"; ... sscanf(string_two, "%lf", &two);` expects to scan a *string*.  `string_two[]` is not a *string* as it lacks a *null character*.  Result: *undefined behavior* (UB).

Solution: Insure `string_two[]` is a *string*.